# How does one perform Wudu if they have injuries?

Tags: wudu

If someone performs wudu that has an area of the body that is injured or would cause discomfort/pain if pouring water over that particular part of the body, what would be the best cause of action?

Answer (score 2):

There is two option. They are:

1. If you have nothing to cover the part of your body which is injured like bandage, then you should do Tayammum.
2. Otherwise, if the part is covered(may be with bandage or anything) then you can wash the part of your body that is uncovered. All praise is of Allah

This is the most convenient way