# Can’t wash my feet because of surgery

Tags: wudu

My surgeon said that I can’t make the one of the feet wet, but i still need to pray, how can i make my salah vaild?

Comment: The basic ruling is if the wound is covered one should *[wipe over it(masah)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masah#:~:text=Masah%20(Arabic%3A%20%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%AD)%20refers,in%20religious%20terms%20by%20God.)*. If the wound isn't covered and touch of water may/can cause harm, one should perform *[dry-ablution (tayamum)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tayammum)*.

Answer (score 1):

[How does one perform Wudu if they have injuries?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/53596/how-does-one-perform-wudu-if-they-have-injuries) describes the general rulings. If neither water nor any dry matter for Tayammum should be applied for medical reasons, you simply do what is possible (wash the other foot, arms, face...) and strike with clean hands over the injured foot ([quote](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/12938/if-one-has-wounds-on-ones-face-and-arms-can-one-do-tayamum/)).